# define an attribute of a many-to-many association as unique

Tags: sql

Is it possible to define an attribute of a many-to-many association as unique?
Can I only use Unique with entities?
For example i have two entity with association GO that have an attribute d:

```
A(ID,t)      ID=primary key
B(u,c)       u= primary key
GO(d,ID_A,u_B).    d=unique??????
```

Association GO is many to many with A and B. I want define attribute d of GO association as unique. Can i do it?

Comment: You would need to add more details and specify what exactly you're asking about. Ideally with some examples. You can create unique index with composite key so most likely you can.

Comment: if you're going to add more details here, please just edit and add them to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can, but you need to specify that unique constraint not on `d`, but on these columns you build a relation to. Basing on your comments, I prepared a postgres example ([fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7QXqShxdGCkkmYmAbFLBFZ/2)):

```sql
create table A(
  id int primary key,
  t varchar(10)
 );
 create table B(
   u int primary key,
   c varchar(10)
  );
  
create table GO_(
  ID_A int references A(id),
  u_B int references B(u),
  unique (ID_A, u_b)
);
  
insert into A values (1, 'a'), (2, 'b');
insert into B values (1, 'x'), (2, 'y');
```

With that we can put these entities into `GO_` table (please note that `GO` is semi restricted word in sql):

```sql
insert into GO_ values (1, 1), (2, 2), (2, 1);
```

But that will raise an error, because of **unique (ID_A, u_b)** constraint.

```sql
insert into GO_ values (1, 1);
```

Comment: I have a question: but Table A and Table B have a primary key, why do you put unique unique (ID_A, u_b)?ID_A and u_b are primary keys of Table GO and foreign key so they are automatically unique(i can't have same alue of ID_A and u_b) in Table GO

Comment: Primary keys (`A.id`, `B.u`) are kind of constrains for the given tables and they enforce uniqueness in them. But that fact that it is a primary key doesn't change in any tables with relation to it (`GO_` in this case, so it has to be declared separately. It could be done for `ID_A` or `u_B` columns, but if you wan't to have unique a combination, you can create `UNIQUE` specifying two columns.

Comment: The best way to observe what does it change - go to the fiddle I linked in my response, uncomment that last insert - the error will be raised. Then comment out that line with `unique`, and try to run again, it will pass now.